# Error while pulling which channel published the song using Distube package

Tags: discord, discord.js, distube

I'm doing a 'Now Playing' command using distube.js, but when I try to pull the information from which channel published the song it comes out as 'undefined' [nowplaying embed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGYSw.png)

These are the [track informations](https://srcb.in/w8aW5kmDdJ).

Does anyone have any tips to help me?

The code I have so far

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { errorbuilder } = require("../../handlers/functions");
const ee = require("../../botconfig/embed.json");
const bar = require(`stylish-text`)

module.exports = {
  name: "nowplaying",
  description: "Mostra os detalhes da música que está tocando",
  permissions: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  usage: "",
  aliases: ["np", "nowplay"],
  execute: async (client, message, args, Discord, cmd) => {
    try {
      const { channel } = message.member.voice;
      if (!channel)
        return message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
          .setFooter(ee.footertext)
          .setTitle(`❌ ERROR | Por favor entre em um canal primeiro`)
        );
      if (!client.distube.getQueue(message))
        return message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
          .setFooter(ee.footertext)
          .setTitle(`❌ ERROR | Eu não estou tocando nada`)
          .setDescription(`Fila vazia`)
        );
      if (client.distube.getQueue(message) && channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id)
        return message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
          .setFooter(ee.footertext)
          .setTitle(`❌ ERROR | Por favor entre no **meu** canal`)
          .setDescription(`Canal: <#${message.guild.me.voice.channel.id}>`)
        );

      let queue = client.distube.getQueue(message);
      let track = queue.songs[0];
      console.log(track)

      function toReadableTime(given) {
        var time = given;
        var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(time / 60);
        var seconds = "0" + (time - minutes * 60);
        return minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);
      }

      const current = Math.floor(queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime / 1000) //ms --> seconds
      const end = track.duration //video in seconds

      const value = (current * (100 / end) / 5)

      bar.default.full = "█";
      bar.default.empty = " - ";
      bar.default.start = "";
      bar.default.end = "";
      bar.default.text = "{bar}";

      let npEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(ee.color)
        .setFooter(ee.footertext)
        .setTitle(`:musical_note: ${track.name}`)
        .setURL(track.url)
        .setThumbnail(track.thumbnail)
        .addField("Views", `:eye: \`${track.views}\``, true)
        .addField("Likes", `:thumbsup: \`${track.likes}\``, true)
        .addField("Dislikes", `:thumbsdown: \`${track.dislikes}\``, true)
        .addField("Voice Channel", `<#${message.guild.me.voice.channel.id}>`, true)
        .addField("By", `${track.channelName}`, true)
        .addField('Play/Resume', client.distube.isPaused(message) === true ? "▶" : "⏸", true)
        .addField("Duration: ", `${toReadableTime(current)} - [${bar.progress(20, value)}] - ${track.formattedDuration}`)

      message.channel.send(npEmbed)
      message.delete();
    } catch (e) {
      errorbuilder(e, message)
    }
  }
}
```

possibly useful information

**Discord.js version:** 12.5.3
**Distube version:** 2.8.15
**Stylish-text version:** 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what `channelName` is, I cant find it anywhere in your [track information](https://sourceb.in/w8aW5kmDdJ)
change this line:

```js
 .addField("By", `${track.channelName}`, true) //change this
 .addField("By", `${track.name.split(" - ")[0]}`, true) //to this
```

> NOTE: If every song you play as the artists name infront of the songs name, seperated with a `-` this should work all the time.

alternatively you could just set the name, of the youtube channel there like this:

```js
 .addField("By", `${track.info.videoDetails.ownerChannelName}`, true)
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I wanna display thhe name of the uploader so i copied the third line of code but I'm finding [this error message](https://srcb.in/GrgQxBjhVI)

Comment: aight sorry mate, I missread the json. I made some changes, and now it should work